# reboot automatically when kernel is upgraded

Tags: unattended-upgrades

I'm using unattended upgrades and I want to reboot automatically when kernel is upgraded.

Is that possible?

Comment: Hello. It may help to know what version of Ubuntu you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up automatic reboot after Unattended Upgrades has upgraded/installed something that requires reboot. That includes installing new kernels.

Related configuration variables:

```
// Automatically reboot *WITHOUT CONFIRMATION* if
//  the file /var/run/reboot-required is found after the upgrade
//Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "false";

// Automatically reboot even if there are users currently logged in
// when Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot is set to true
//Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-WithUsers "true";

// If automatic reboot is enabled and needed, reboot at the specific
// time instead of immediately
//  Default: "now"
//Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:00";
```

Save your preferred settings in file */etc/apt/apt.conf.d/52unattended-upgrades-local* (so that you do not have to modify *50unattended-upgrades* provided by the package).

You can see explicitly set configuration values by
`apt-config dump unattended-upgrade`

Unfortunately, you can not list all current values.
https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/issues/245

You could see more documentation (of the latest version) at https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades

Unfortunately not all supported options are explained there, though:
https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/issues/246
https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/issues/318

Answer (score 0):

Assumption, valid at least for:

```
$ source /etc/os-release && echo $NAME $VERSION
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)
```

For what it is worth; this (Bash) function DISPLAYS whether there are packages waiting for a reboot:

```
rereq () 
{ 
    ( file=/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs;
    if [ ! -f $file ]; then
        echo "There should be no reboot required, $file does not exist.";
    else
      echo -e "\n*** $file ***"
      cat "$file";
    fi )
}
```

... a slight rewrite and you'll have the base for an "automatic reboot".

I believe though that you need more criteria for that reboot; you might not be happy if it decides to do it's thing when you're in the midst of some (possibly important) unsaved work.

Comment: More info on Bash and how you can use it; http://tldp.org -> Bash guides. Additionally you will possibly need a `cron` job to get it done.